# understanding the nearest neighbors image resizing algorithm

Tags: image, algorithm

I was reading about [nearest-neighbor interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest-neighbor_interpolation) and am not sure that I understand how it works. Would the following be a correct interpretation of the algorithm? Say we want to stretch our image by a factor of 3, from a 2 by 2 sized image to 6 by 6:

```
Map every pixel value in the old image to its location in the resized image. 
Refer to these as 'landmarks'.
 - For example, (0,0) -> (0,0)
                (0,1) -> (0,3) 
                ...
Starting at (0,1), for every pixel in the resized image that doesn't have a value,
assign to that pixel the value of the closest landmark.
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. The only problem is how you will find this nearest point. I am afraid, that with this formulation it would be not so easy. Try to write the algorithm in some pseudocode and the community will check it.

Comment: @Gangnus is it appropriate to use an algorithm like breadth first search, checking in each of the four cardinal and ordinal directions?

Comment: Algorithm is OK. But it can be formulated in many ways. The shortest or simplest for explanation is not always the best for implementation in code. And rarely is effective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to make a small adjustment to the positioning of your 'landmarks'. Instead of putting the first one at (0,0), let's put it at (1,1):

```
_ _ _ _ _ _
_ x _ _ x _
_ _ _ _ _ _
_ _ _ _ _ _
_ x _ _ x _
_ _ _ _ _ _
```

`x` marks the landmarks, the `_` characters are undefined pixels.
We now have landmarks at (1,1), (1,4), (4,1) and (4,4). How do we know which pixels in the original image correspond to these landmarks? The easiest way is to use integer division to divide by the scaling factor, in this case 3:

```
1 div 3 = 0
4 div 3 = 1
```

We can now map each of our landmark pixels to its corresponding pixel in the original image:

```
landmark    original
  (1,1)  =>   (0,0)
  (1,4)  =>   (0,1)
  (4,1)  =>   (1,0)
  (4,4)  =>   (1,1)
```

Now, what happens if we try this with the other pixels in the resized image? If we take, say, pixel (2,3), can we determine which pixel it's closest to in the original image? Well,

```
2 mod 3 = 0
3 mod 3 = 1
```

So the corresponding pixel in the original image is (0,1). This is the same pixel that corresponds to our landmark (1,4), so that must be our nearest neighbor. Our resized image with the new pixel would look like this:

```
_ _ _ _ _ _
_ x _ _ x _
_ _ _ _ _ _
_ _ @ _ _ _
_ @ _ _ x _
_ _ _ _ _ _
```

I've changed the symbol for our new pixel and the landmark pixel that also corresponds to the landmark (0,1) to `@`.
But we calculated the original position corresponding to our new pixel without any reference to the landmark, so do we really need that landmark at all? Well, no we don't. All we have to do is to divide each pixel coordinate by the scaling factor using integer division (or floor or truncate or whatever your programming language calls it; but not round). This gives us the following pseudocode:

```
Input:  Original[][] - the original image as a 2-dimensional array
        k - the scalar scaling factor
Output: Resized[][] - the resized image

for all elements (i,j) in Resized
    Resized[i][j] := Original[i div k][j div k]
end
```

In fact, if you use floating-point division and truncate/floor, you can extend this to accept non-integer scaling factors >= 1.